# Set position of dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used a dialog box popup on click of a link. When I click on a link background of parent page change to white color & dialog box is seen at center.

But when I am going to mimize the browser size/screen, the popup moves to the right. I want dialog box popup in the center whether the browser screen is minimized or not.

I use the following jquery & css & code for dialog box

1. jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css
2. jquery-ui.min.js

Code :

```js
$('.addlink').click(function() {
    $("#add_action").dialog({
        modal: true, 
        draggable: false, 
        resizable: true, 
        minWidth: 200, 
        width:560,
        minheight:98, 
        zIndex: 50000},
        {position:[400,120]
    });
});
```

Comment: can you show give complete code ?

Comment: try to accept answers if your issue is resolved!
Seems like you never accept the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $("#add_action").dialog("option", "position", "center");
});
```

Comment: It works but only when I change browser size..by default it doesn't open popup box

Comment: You mean to say you dont get dialog box when you click on addlink?

Answer (score 1):

### Part1:

Specifies where the dialog should be displayed. Possible values:
1) a single string representing position within viewport: 'center', 'left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom'.
2) an array containing an x,y coordinate pair in pixel offset from left, top corner of viewport (e.g. [350,100])
3) an array containing x,y position string values (e.g. ['right','top'] for top right corner).
Code examples

Initialize a dialog with the position option specified.

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ position: "top" });
```

Get or set the position option, after init.

```
//getter
var position = $( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "position" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "position", "top" );
```

### Part2:

Setting the [`position` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-position) will force this, so just use the same selector covering all your dialogs where I use `#dialog` here (if it doesn't find them no action is taken, like all jQuery):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog("option", "position", "center");
});
```

[Here's that same jQuery UI demo page adding only the code above](http://jsfiddle.net/39GqM/), we're just adding a handler to the window's `resize` event with [`.resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/), so it triggers the re-center at the appropriate time.
    ​